# Orbeon forms builder with MS SQL

Tags: orbeon

I lose all form data and get an error saying error performing search when I set the following property in Orbeon Form Builder properties - `local.xml` file

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.persistence.provider.*.*.*" value="sqlserver"/>
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with your SQL Server setup. I assume you followed the instructions in http://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/persistence/relational-db.html, did the appropriate setup at the Tomcat level, and created the schema and tables in your SQL Server, correct? Assuming you did, I'd recommend you set your log level per the [Development configuration](http://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/xforms-logging.html#development-configuration), restart Tomcat, reproduce the problem, and inspect the orbeon.log for relevant errors. You'll let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes I think it was something wrong with my MS SQL version, Thank you!

Comment: Excellent; I'm glad you figured it out. Those configs can be tricky, and with different things to setup at different levels.